# Can we use zero conditional mean assumption in linear model to prove the error epsilon is independent of the feature X?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, linear-model

I know the zero conditional mean assumption in the linear model is 
[image]. But can we use this assumption to prove the residual is independent of x? I tried iterated rule of conditional expectation but it seems I got stuck there. Or if we can not, is there any example to show that this assumption can not guarantee the residual is independent of x?

Comment: Consider a simple linear regression with just one predictor but where the error gets bigger as $x$ increases. We could still have an expectation of zero, but the error and the predictor certainly aren’t independent.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand why we could still have an expectation of zero if the error gets bigger as x increases, could you give an example?

Comment: $\epsilon_i \sim N(0, x_i^2)$ has an expected value of 0 for every error term, yet the error depends on $x_i$.

Comment: Oh I get it. Thanks!

Comment: @Dave - you might want to combine your comments into an answer, since they do answer the question!

Answer (score 0):

Consider a simple linear regression with just one predictor but where the error gets bigger as $x$ increases. We could still have an expectation of zero, but the error and the predictor certainly aren’t independent.

For example, $\epsilon_i\sim N(0,x_i^2)$ has an expectation of $0$ for every $i$ but does not have the error independent of the predictor.